# Modifying .vcf files

Tags: vcf, text-processing

I have 200 .vcf files like this on a Linux system:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT
chr4    5708160 .   G   GATAAC
chr4    30280292    .   C   CACGTAT
chr6    166253422   .   C   CCTTTCT
chr11   21931340    .   A   AACACACGC
chr12   118404422   .   G   GCACACA
chr15   22672047    .   T   TAAGTAGATTTAAG
chr16   32656293    .   ATGATT  A
```

I want to modify my .vcf files in this way

For instance if the reference allele in `REF column` is `TCTC` and alteration allele in `ALT column` is `T`, because T is the first common nucleotide in both reference and alteration so we remove `T` from `ALT column` so REF would remain as `TCTC` and ALT would be `-` . In total I mean removing whatever in ALT which is common with the first allele in REF.

Any help please?

This is what I got by @haci's code

```
> head(var.annovar.maf2[1:6,1:13])
   Tumor_Sample_Barcode Chromosome Start_Position End_Position Reference_Allele Tumor_Seq_Allele2 Hugo_Symbol Variant_Classification
1:                  new       chr1       89616151     89616151                G                 T        GBP7      Missense_Mutation
2:                  new      chr16       20556547     20556547                C                 G      ACSM2B      Missense_Mutation
3:                  new      chr17       66992092     66992092                C                 A       ABCA9      Missense_Mutation
4:                  new      chr20       13251339     13251339                C                 T        ISM1                 Silent
5:                  new       chr1          56987        56987               CA                 -           .                   <NA>
6:                  new       chr1        4133415      4133415               AG                 -           .                   <NA>
             tx   exon txChange aaChange Variant_Type
1:    NM_207398  exon6  c.C733A  p.L245I          SNP
2: NM_001105069 exon10 c.G1213C  p.G405R          SNP
3:    NM_080283 exon26 c.G3499T p.G1167C          SNP
4:    NM_080826  exon2  c.C327T  p.N109N          SNP
5:         <NA>   <NA>     <NA>     <NA>          DEL
6:         <NA>   <NA>     <NA>     <NA>          DEL
>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the new question! But please also include the output you expect. For example, your last line looks like a deletion of 5 nucleotides, changing `ATGATT` to `A`, what do you want to see for that line?

Comment: Please provide a final expected output as suggested by @terdon. I think I may understand what you mean, however what would you do in the case of the final row in the table - for chr16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is a reason that the first nucleotide of the `ALT` is the same as that of `REF` in `VCF` files, however I was not able to find a reference for this.

If you really need to do this for some reason, you will need to compare the alt and ref entries base by base starting from base 1 of each and until a mismatch. Here is some R code doing that:

```
library(data.table)
my_csv <- fread("example_vcf.txt")
print(my_csv)

# loop over each row
for(i in 1:nrow(my_csv)) {

  # make "strings" from the ref and alt columns, make "arrays" of letters out of these strings
  ref <- as.character(my_csv[i, "REF"])
  ref_array <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(my_csv[i, "REF"]), split = ""))

  alt <- as.character(my_csv[i, "ALT"])
  alt_array <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(my_csv[i, "ALT"]), split = ""))

  # which of the ref alt-pair shorter and how long
  shortest <- c(nchar(ref), nchar(alt))[which.min(c(nchar(ref), nchar(alt)))]

  # compare ref and alt base by base, remove from alt if same nucleotide present in both, stop at first mismatch
  index <- 1
  new_alt <- alt_array
  while(index <= shortest) {
    if (ref_array[index] == alt_array[index]) {
      new_alt <- new_alt[-1]
    } else {
      break()
    }
    index <- index + 1
  }

  my_csv[i,"ALT"] <- paste(new_alt, collapse = "")

  # use "-" if alt is empty
  if (my_csv[i,"ALT"] == "") {
    my_csv[i,"ALT"] <- "-"
  }
}

print(my_csv)
```

I have added some test cases at the end of the sample piece in your sample and the code is adding another column so that the changes made to the `ALT` are easier to see:

```
> print(my_csv)
    #CHROM       POS ID    REF            ALT       NEW_ALT
 1:   chr4   5708160  .      G         GATAAC         ATAAC
 2:   chr4  30280292  .      C        CACGTAT        ACGTAT
 3:   chr6 166253422  .      C        CCTTTCT        CTTTCT
 4:  chr11  21931340  .      A      AACACACGC      ACACACGC
 5:  chr12 118404422  .      G        GCACACA        CACACA
 6:  chr15  22672047  .      T TAAGTAGATTTAAG AAGTAGATTTAAG
 7:  chr16  32656293  . ATGATT              A             -
 8: chrXXX       XXX  .   TCTC              T             -
 9: chrXXX       XXX  .   TCTC           TCTC             -
10: chrXXX       XXX  .   TCTC             TA             A
11: chrXXX       XXX  .   TCTC            TAT            AT
```

Comment: Possibly due to left-normalisation?

https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Variant_Normalization

Comment: The reason given in the specification is to avoid empty fields (see §1.6.1 Fixed fields, 4 REF). In particular for insertions `chr4  5708161  .  -  ATAAC` it would be unclear whether the insertion being described was supposed to be before or after the base at 5708161. In `chr4  5708160  .  G  GATAAC` the anchoring G makes it crystal clear that the insertion is between the bases at positions 5708160 and 5708161.

Comment: Thank you to be such nice people. Actually I am trying to annotate my INDELs called by Strelka caller using ANNOVAR but annovar was complaining about something then I guessed that may be allele repetition.  @haci your code worked on annovar but annovar identifies all as SNP or DELETION and no INSERTION. To be honest I even don't know how to change INDEL vcf to be correctly recognized by ANNOVAR. However what I assumed would work you helped me to try that and thank you. It is not your fault rather I must first know what change needed for INDEL for annovar annotation. I posted results above